# How do I bound a generic type with a trait that requires a lifetime parameter if I create the reference inside the function?

Tags: generics, rust, lifetime

I want to implement a generic `fibonacci` function that works with any type implementing `Zero`, `One`, and `AddAssign`. I first implemented a version that works fine, but is specialized for `num::BigUint` ([see on play.rust-lang.org](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=d3afb763eb57c9582647f7748f170093&version=nightly)). I than came up with the following generic implementation ([see on play.rust-lang.org](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=47e1273ace46a1eaa89b8277c25e5691&version=nightly)):

```
extern crate num;

use num::{One, Zero};
use std::mem::swap;
use std::ops::AddAssign;

fn fib<T: Zero + One + AddAssign<&T>>(n: usize) -> T {
    let mut f0 = Zero::zero();
    let mut f1 = One::one();
    for _ in 0..n {
        f0 += &f1;
        swap(&mut f0, &mut f1);
    }
    f0
}
```

This doesn't compile:

```
error[E0106]: missing lifetime specifier
 --> src/main.rs:7:34
  |
7 | fn fib<T: Zero + One + AddAssign<&T>>(n: usize) -> T {
  |                                  ^ expected lifetime parameter
```

Rust wants me to add a lifetime parameter to `AddAssign<&T>` but I don't know how to express the lifetime of `f1`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to use [Higher Rank Trait Bounds](https://doc.rust-lang.org/beta/nomicon/hrtb.html).  This one means basically "For any lifetime `'a`, `T` satisfies the `AddAssign<&'a T>` trait":

```
fn fib<T>(n: usize) -> T
where
    for<'a> T: Zero + One + AddAssign<&'a T>,
```

I also had to change the way `fib` is called because the compiler couldn't figure out the return type, which could be literally any type that implements those traits. Declaring `x`'s type gives sufficient context to the compiler so that it knows what you want.

```
fn main() {
    let x: num::BigUint = fib(10);
    // let x = fib::<BigUint>(10); // Also works
    println!("fib(10) = {}", x);
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=bccb848063239d94852719a55a5c1598&version=nightly)

Comment: That makes sense. The generic type argument needs to come from *somewhere*. Thank you for superb explanation, upvoted ;)

Comment: Thank you very much, I didn't know about  *Higher Rank Trait Bounds*. This answers my question.