# Declaring lifetimes for Trait parameters taking references

Tags: rust

I'm almost certain that this has been asked in multiple ways before. But I'm not really sure on what to search for.

I'm trying write a faculty function that operates on `Integer`s, and since integers can be `BigInts` I would like to try to use references as much as possible. And also of course to better understand how to use lifetimes and references.

The code looks like this

```rust
pub fn faculty<T>(mut n: T) -> T
where
    T: num::Integer + num::Unsigned + MulAssign<&T> + SubAssign<&T>,
{
    let one: T = T::one();
    let mut result: T = T::one();

    while n > one {
        result *= &n;
        n -= &one;
    }

    result
}
```

However, the compiler tells me that I'm missing lifetime specifiers for `MulAssign` and `SubAssign`, and it seems a bit off adding lifetime parameters to a function that neither takes a reference nor returns one.

I tried doing something like

```rust
pub fn faculty<'a, 'b, 'c, T: 'c>(mut n: T) -> T
where
    T: num::Integer + num::Unsigned + MulAssign<&'a T> + SubAssign<&'b T>,
```

Which gives the error "The parameter type `T` may not live long enough".

So, how do write my function correctly, so I can use operations like `result *= &n;` in my code?

Comment: I believe your question is answered by the answers of [generic type without a lifetime parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47996700/155423). If you disagree, please [edit] your question to explain the differences. Otherwise, we can mark this question as already answered.

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47997981/3131852) to the linked question applies here as well.

Comment: Ah, thank you. That gave me exactly what I needed :-).